# Batch file editing .csv file - delete column; get part of the string; remove repetitives

Tags: batch-file, csv, cmd, substring

I am using Windows and got some CSV files with only part of the data from the **Third Column** that is interested to me. Below is a sample of a few rows of my raw data:

```
Column.1     Column.2     Column.3         Column.4     Column.5     Column.6  
blah         blah         A/B/C/D/x/x/x    blah         blah         blah
blah         blah         A/B/C/D/x/x/x    blah         blah         blah   
blah         blah         E/F/G/H/x/x/x    blah         blah         blah
```

What I am trying to do with it is:
1. Delete other columns but only keep Column.3
2. Extract the strings up to the 4th forward slash from Column.3 and delete the rest
3. Remove the repetitive entries

So the output will be some thing like:

```
A/B/C/D  
E/F/G/H
```

Hope this is a better way to explain what I am after.

Cheers,
Alan

Answer (score 1):

## update

Try reading through `HELP FOR` in CMD

By enabling `setlocal enableddelayedexpansion` we can create an array like structure:

This will iterate the rows of "filename.csv" setting each line to a temp variable called LINE.

Then for each token(s) "1,2,3,4,5" split by the delimiter "\" (`delims=\`) in `LINE` and stores them in `row` we can then call them back after the 2nd for ends as shown.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
SET /A COUNT=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (d.csv) do (
    set LINE="%%A"
    set /A COUNT+=1
    for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,* delims=\" %%a in (!LINE!) do (
        set row[0]=%%a
        set row[1]=%%b
        set row[2]=%%c
        set row[3]=%%d
        set row[4]=%%e
        set row[5]=%%f
)
        echo This is row: !COUNT!
        echo This is column A: !row[0]!
        echo This is column B: !row[1]!
        echo This is column C: !row[2]!
        echo This is column D: !row[3]!
        echo This is column E: !row[4]!
        echo This is column F: !row[5]!
        echo.
)
REM this is substring manipulation
echo !row[5]:~1,2!
echo !row[5]:~0,2!
echo !row[5]:~3,5!
echo !row[5]:~-3!
endlocal
```

## filename.csv:

```
A1\anotherB\C\and a d\blah0\blah1\blah1
A2\stuff2\C\D\blah2\blah3\blah1
A3\B\the last C\D\blah4\pizza5\blah1
A4\B\C\D\blah6\blah7\blah1
```

## output:

```
C:\Users\UserBob\Desktop\RANDOM\32>3.bat
This is row: 1
This is column A: A1
This is column B: anotherB
This is column C: C
This is column D: and a d
This is column E: blah0
This is column F: blah1\blah1

This is row: 2
This is column A: A2
This is column B: stuff2
This is column C: C
This is column D: D
This is column E: blah2
This is column F: blah3\blah1

This is row: 3
This is column A: A3
This is column B: B
This is column C: the last C
This is column D: D
This is column E: blah4
This is column F: pizza5\blah1

This is row: 4
This is column A: A4
This is column B: B
This is column C: C
This is column D: D
This is column E: blah6
This is column F: blah7\blah1
```

Output continued this is the substring output (`echo !row[5]:~1,2!`):

```
la
bl
h7\bl
ah1
```

So for your interest you would use `!row[3]:~num,num!`

Comment: Thanks jmunsch. Could you please explain it to me a bit? As I cannot see where it says only work on Column.3 and it is preferred to keep the first backslashes. Ta

Comment: I updated the answer. I tried to show how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=/" %%a IN (q25716731.txt) DO SET "$%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d=%%a/%%b/%%c/%%d"
(
 FOR /F "tokens=2delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO ECHO(%%a
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25716731.txt` containing some data for my testing. The filename is not significant.
Produces newfile.txt.

Note that you explicitly state "backslash" and then provide forward slashes in the data sample. Routine produced to work on forward slashes - change for backslash should be obvious.

---

Revision for clarified data and output requirements

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: remove variables starting $
FOR /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
FOR /f "skip=1tokens=3delims= " %%s IN (q25716731.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=/" %%a IN ("%%s") DO SET "$%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d=%%a/%%b/%%c/%%d"
)
(
 FOR /F "tokens=2delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO ECHO(%%a
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q25716731.txt` containing your data for my testing.
Produces newfile.txt

The "skip=1" skips the column-header line.

It's still not clear whether the actual data is truly CSV or actually fixed-column format. Assumption is that `blah` does not contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks Magoo. 
It partially works because I didn't state clearly enough that in Column 3, I do have data in other format. Could you please take a second look to help me to, 
1. Delete other columns, only keep column 3, and
2. Delete data in other formats in column 3, only keep A/B/C/D.

Comment: The crystal ball is on the blink today. How do you distinguish between col 3 in required format and col3 in 'other format' - to be deleted. You say you want to keep only columns 3 and 2 and then to keep A/B/C/D - which are columns 1 to 4 according to your original info.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I have updated the question and hope it make a better sense now. Could you please take another look? Ta